Mean score of the Composite Variable
I have three items(Likert scale from 5 to 1) measuring opportunity recognition. I was getting negative cronbachs alpha value. Hence, I reverse-coded and got the Cronbach's alpha of 0.83.
I will be using the mean scores of these items as a composite variable to measure Opportunity recognition. The composite variable will be the dependent variable in regression analysis. So, to calculate the mean score, should I use the unreversed data or reversed data?

You need to use reverse-coded items for items that are, well, reverse-coded, for both reliability calculations and for composite variable calculation.
For instance, if I have the following 3 items for measuring how much people like parties:

Parties are fun
I don't particularly like parties
I go to parties any chance I get

I would need reverse-code number 2 prior to reliability analysis and prior to averaging them into composite score. However, I would of course NOT reverse-code items 1 and 3.
